# Why am I recieving a JMSBytesMessage when I'm sending an OBject message using Spring and MQ Queue

Tags: java, spring, jms, ibm-mq

So I'm sending an object using Spring and IBM MQ Queue:

```
public void sendObjectMessage(final Object message) {

//  jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(message);

    jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator()
      {
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException
        {
        ObjectMessage outMessage = session.createObjectMessage((Serializable) message);
        return(outMessage);
        }
      }); 
}
```

And during debugging I can see that I am indeed sending it as an object message. But using Spring's listener implementation I am picking up the messages in the onMessage() method as JMSBytesMessages????

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    System.out.println(">>>>>>> Recieved in onMessage");
    System.out.println(message.getClass());
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
>>>>>>> Recieved in onMessage
class com.ibm.jms.JMSBytesMessage
```

Anybody know whats going on here? This is difficult to debug as it seems to be happening on the queue???

Thanks for your help

P.S I've also tried to catch the message using

```
if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
    object = ((ObjectMessage) message).getObject();
}
```

and

```
if (message instanceof JMSBytesMessage) {
    System.out.println("ITS A BYTES MESSAGE!!!!!!!!!!!"); 
}
```

Neither of which work???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first guess is, that you're using WebSphere AppServer and your JMS queue object (in JNDI) is configured to be a native MQ series client, i.e. you create a JMSObjectMessage which you hand over to the session and then MQSeries thinks it has to convert to BytesMessage.

Comment: Are you using WAS? And if so, are you using the same JMS queue definition for sending and receiving?

Comment: Oh, sorry didn't see that you're using Spring - then its propably another story

Comment: Not using appserver this is a thin client. I think you maybe right when you saythe MQSeries is converting the message though

Comment: how do you define the properties of queue on the sender and on the receiver side.

Comment: Could you be more specific as i dont want to post my whole config on a public forum

Comment: Check if you're message on the queue is in RFH2 format (you can use tools like visual edit or WebSphere MQ Explorer). If they are, then the sending side is most propably correct.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. In my case, I was using the wrong transport type:

```xml
<bean id="mqQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <property name="baseQueueName" value="..." />
    <property name="targetClient">
        <util:constant static-field="com.ibm.mq.jms.JMSC.MQJMS_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Instead it should have been:

```xml
<bean id="mqQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <property name="baseQueueName" value="..." />
    <property name="targetClient">
        <util:constant static-field="com.ibm.mq.jms.JMSC.MQJMS_CLIENT_JMS_COMPLIANT" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: This has also solved the same problem for us, whereas the selected answer above was not really helpful. Adding the MQJMS_CLIENT_JMS_COMPLIANT property made all the difference! Thanks