# Spring-JMS: Sending a JMSObjectMessage to WebSphere MQ, but receiving a JMSBytesMessage

Tags: java, spring, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I use Spring's JmsTemplate to send an ObjectMessage to a MQ Queue:

```java
this.jmsTemplate.send(this.queue, new MessageCreator() {
    public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
        MyPayload payload = new MyPayload();
        payload.setSomething(...);
        return session.createObjectMessage(payload);
    }
 });
```

The sent message is of type `com.ibm.jms.JMSObjectMessage`, but the corresponding destination receives a message of type `com.ibm.jms.JMSBytesMessage`:

```java
Message message = this.jmsTemplate.receive(this.queue);
```

Any idea, why and where the conversion takes place?

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150006/why-am-i-recieving-a-jmsbytesmessage-when-im-sending-and-object-message-using-sp) is not really answered.

Further information: A TextMessage is received as `com.ibm.jms.JMSTextMessage`, an ObjectMessage with just a string inside is converted to a `com.ibm.jms.JMSBytesMessage`, too.

Comment: Does `MyPayload` implement `Serializable`?

Comment: Yes, it implements `Serializable`.

Comment: Can `MyPayload` be found in class path at server side?

Comment: Yes, both components share the same jar file containing `MyPayload`.

Comment: Try to send text message and object message with string inside. If you get the same result, I guess something is wrong with the queue configuration: it cannot translate byte buffer into object. Otherwise something is wrong with either your payload or classpath at server side.

Comment: Do you have any news?

Comment: The same behaviour occurs with Strings inside an ObjectMessage (see my addition to the original question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, I was using the wrong transport type:

```xml
<bean id="mqQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <property name="baseQueueName" value="..." />
    <property name="targetClient">
        <util:constant static-field="com.ibm.mq.jms.JMSC.MQJMS_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Instead it should have been:

```xml
<bean id="mqQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <property name="baseQueueName" value="..." />
    <property name="targetClient">
        <util:constant static-field="com.ibm.mq.jms.JMSC.MQJMS_CLIENT_JMS_COMPLIANT" />
    </property>
</bean>
```